# what does the small x means in lapply

Tags: r

I have the variables:

```
trims<- c(0,0.1,0.2,0.5)
x<-rcauchy(100)
```

and the following operation:

```
lapply(trims, mean, x=x)
```

what does the small x refer to in this case? The documentation for lapply does not explain it well either. I do know that for lapply function, it takes a function and apply it to each element of the list, which I believe is trim in this case. How does x come in then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we use anonymous function, it will be clear.

```
res <- lapply(trims, function(y) mean(x, trim=y))
res1 <- lapply(trims, mean, x=x)
identical(res, res1)
#[1] TRUE
```

The `lapply` loops through each of the 'trims' and as `mean` has first argument of `x` and second argument of `trim` and the first argument is already mentioned with `x=x` i.e. the object created with `rauncy`, naturally the the second argument i.e. `trim` selects the values in 'trimws'